# Typescript Decorator with Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Does not work below codes :

```
function deco<T>(){
    return function(target, key){
        // before
        // target[key] = new Decorated<T>();
        // edited
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get(){
             return new Decorated<T>();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Decorated<T> {
    set(values: T){
    }
}

class MyDecos {
    @deco<{a: number}>() a;
    @deco<{b: string}>() b;
}

const test = new MyDecos;
test.a.set(); // want to throw error
test.a.set({a: '1'); // want to throw error
test.b.set({b: 1); // want to throw error
```

have any wrong with generic?
assistant displayed `values: any`

I want to `Test.set` methods working with Generic from decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators can't change the structure of the class, this limitation is by design. We can use mixins to achieve mutation of the class as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743).

Without a more complete example however, I am not sure why you don't just instatiate the field directly with an insatnce of `Decorated<T>`. The decorator version does not seem to add much in this case:

```
class MyDecos {
    a = new Decorated<{ a: number }>();
    b = new Decorated<{ b: string }>();
}

const test = new MyDecos;
test.a.set(); // error
test.a.set({ a: '1'); //error
test.b.set({ b: 1); //  error
```

**Note** Your current decorator implementation is not ok, you assign `Decorated` to the `target`, `target` is the class not an instance of the class so only one `Decorated` object will exist for **all** instances of the class, my guess this is meant to hold instance state so the implementation will cause problems.

Comment: how about decorator using getter for change the instance?, I already tried, then got same result with question.

Comment: @styliss Yes you could solve the one instance problem creating a property nstead. That still will not change the structure of the class, you just can't do that from a decorator, you could declare the type explicitly,but that would mean duplicating the type which is not very nice. Again not sure why this must be a decorator, if you provide a more complete example to see why a decorator is needed maybe we can come up with a better solution

Comment: the result class are using property key and parent class of decorator, and reference to other decorated property.
`property = new Decorated(this, 'property')` => `@deco() property`